# why Ionic app not working on my phone network but other apps are

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, ionic-framework

Hi Guys this question seems to be different from the league but just need to know whether some buddy ever came across such issue.

I'm using iPhone 6s version 10.0.2 with Jio 4G network(India) and somehow in few days since last week my ios version of Ionic app has stopped working on the phone. It directly shows no Network but other apps in phone like youtube or instagram or any other app is working fine, and app is signed with certificates so not able to debug or see whats happening.

But if I borrowed someone's hotspot even 3G or 4G, app starts working on it.

I don't know the issue is with ios or phone.

Any help will definitely help me and save my day I've production tomorrow.

Comment: Have you tried reproducing it on a copy that you *can* debug? I doubt whether anyone is going to be able to help much with no info to work with....

Comment: Are you using any reachability class in the code?

Comment: What kind of URL is the app trying to access? iOS is getting stricter and stricter with non-HTTPS URLs to the point that (I think) they won't work any more at all. Although if it works on an alternative connection, that couldn't be the issue.

Comment: Perhaps your specific URL is blocked with the provider for some reason? Have you tried accessing it in a browser?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tried loading Url in browser and it's https; it's working but app shows no network connection and this is not happening with emulator or debug build only with released builds on my phone only?..

Comment: Crazy. Step by step debugging is the only thing that comes to mind. What sort of reachability check are you using? Have you tried bypassing the check?

Comment: yes I dod but unfortunately, that nothing is logged clearly.. Thanks